# hide template function from header file

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++17

I have the following use case.

`Messages.h`

```cpp
template <typename Message>
Message deserialize(std::string const &buf);

template <>
RequestHeader deserialize(std::string const &buf);

template <typename Message>
std::string serialize(Message const &msg);

#include "Messages.inl"
```

`Messages.inl`

```cpp
template <typename Message>
Message deserialize(std::string const &buf, bool partial)
{
    Message msg;
    size_t bufSize = buf.length();
    size_t msgSize = sizeof msg;

    if (msgSize > bufSize)
        throw std::underflow_error("Message size exceeds buffer size.");

    if (msgSize < bufSize && !partial)
        throw std::overflow_error("Buffer size exceeds message size.");

    std::memcpy(&msg, &buf[0], (msgSize < bufSize) ? msgSize : bufSize);
    return msg;
}

template <typename Message>
Message deserialize(std::string const &buf)
{
    return deserialize<Message>(buf, false);
}

template <typename Message>
std::string serialize(Message const &msg)
{
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&msg);
    return std::string(ptr, ptr + sizeof msg);
}
```

`Messages.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Messages.h"

template <>
RequestHeader deserialize(std::string const &buf)
{
    return deserialize<RequestHeader>(buf, true);
}
```

The "problem" with this code is, that the template with the signature

```cpp
Message deserialize(std::string const &buf, bool partial)
```

is publicly available through the inclusion of the `*.inl` file in the header by any unit using `Messages.h`.
However, it is just an internal helper to generalize the deserialization and should not be publicly available. If it would be a regular function and not a template, I'd mark it as static to be only visible in the translation unit. But this does not seem to have an effect on templates in inline files.
How would I go about hiding this template from the header file and still derive the other template function and specializations from it? Is it even possible?

Comment: It is not clear whether the helpers are used in one file, only (this is what `static` is suggesting). If this is the case then simply define the helpers in that file.

Comment: The helper is currently used in `Messages.inl` only, which in turn is included in `Messages.h`, which is the external interface where I do not want to expose the helper function.

Comment: C++20 makes this possible via modules: the helpers can be made unavailable to name lookup even though they are (as they must be) available for instantiation.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for the comment, I added a remark on modules in C++20 as well. Are you aware of an online compiler that is able to handle C++ modules?

Comment: @2b-t: Compiler Explorer has several (at varying stages of completion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before C++20** you generally have only two options:

- Either you "hide" the helper functions by moving them to a **namespace** such **`details`** or `helper`. This way one will not see it immediately but can still access them ([Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9e1nLJ2ZB2RyKtqB)):

  ```
  namespace details {
    template <typename Message>
    Message deserialize(std::string const &buf, bool partial) {
      Message msg;
      size_t bufSize = buf.length();
      size_t msgSize = sizeof msg;

      if (msgSize > bufSize)
        throw std::underflow_error("Message size exceeds buffer size.");

      if (msgSize < bufSize && !partial)
        throw std::overflow_error("Buffer size exceeds message size.");

      std::memcpy(&msg, &buf[0], (msgSize < bufSize) ? msgSize : bufSize);
      return msg;
   }
  }

  template <typename Message>
  Message deserialize(std::string const &buf) {
    return details::deserialize<Message>(buf, false);
  }
  ```
- or you put the functions as **static methods inside a `struct`** (or `class`) making the interface `public` and the helper function `protected`. ([Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nqw7Jn9S29lhO1m0))

  ```
  struct message {
    public:
      template <typename Message>
      static Message deserialize(std::string const &buf);

      template <typename Message>
      static std::string serialize(Message const &msg);

    protected:
      template <typename Message>
      static Message deserialize(std::string const &buf, bool partial);
  };

  template <typename Message>
  Message message::deserialize(std::string const &buf) {
    return deserialize<Message>(buf, false);
  }

  template <>
  RequestHeader message::deserialize(std::string const &buf) {
    return deserialize<RequestHeader>(buf, true);
  }
  ```

  In your case you could remove the specialisation with `std::is_same_v<T1,T2>` from `type_traits` or by additionally using `if constexpr` for more complicated conditions ([Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mFpehpwBwwge0YCi)).

If the function is as simple as your version above I would actually try to **eliminate the helper functions altogether with `std::is_same_v<T1,T2>`** as follows ([Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LbNwS6jQVAbSMFC4))

```
  template <typename Message>
  Message deserialize(std::string const &buf) {
    constexpr bool partial = std::is_same_v<Message,RequestHeader>;

    Message msg;
    size_t bufSize = buf.length();
    size_t msgSize = sizeof msg;

    if (msgSize > bufSize)
      throw std::underflow_error("Message size exceeds buffer size.");

    if (msgSize < bufSize && !partial)
      throw std::overflow_error("Buffer size exceeds message size.");

    std::memcpy(&msg, &buf[0], (msgSize < bufSize) ? msgSize : bufSize);
    return msg;
  }
```

---

As pointed out in the comment in **C++20** you could use [**modules**](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-modules).
For this you could create a module `some_module.cppm` holding all functions and marking only the interface with `export`.

```
// some_module.cppm
export module some_module;

template <typename T>
auto invisible_helper(T t) {
  return t*t;
}        

export
template <typename T>
auto visible_function(T t) { 
    return invisible_helper(t);
}
```

In the case below only the function `visible_function` is exported and can be accessed inside `main.cpp`  while `invisible_helper` remains hidden:

```
// main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
import some_module;

int main() {
  std::cout << visible_function(2.0) << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you have `clang++12` installed you can compile the code with the following three commands:

```
clang++ -std=c++2b -fmodules-ts --precompile some_module.cppm -o some_module.pcm
clang++ -std=c++2b -fmodules-ts -c some_module.pcm -o some_module.o
clang++ -std=c++2b -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. some_module.o main.cpp -o main
./main
```